# Can I update Android Support Library from 27.1.1 to AndroidX 1.0.0?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, android-jetpack

I have a complex codebase and I'm trying to be careful before migrating to AndroidX. My support library is currently 27.1.1. Can I migrate it to AndroidX 1.0.0? I have seen people migrate from 28.0.0 to 1.0.0 but not from 27.1.1. What if third party dependencies use older version of support library? Does setting `android.enableJetifier` to true provides backward compatibility for v4, v7, v13 or the library version (26, 27.1, 28)? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Support library 28.0.0 and Androidx 1.0.0 were [built from the same source code](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118392625#comment3), so it'll probably be easier to catch any API-related bugs if you migrate to 28.0.0 first.

Jetifier modifies class files during the build process by replacing all the `android.support` class names with `androidx` and `com.google.android.material` equivalents. This affects every single class file included in your build, even the ones that came from third-party libraries. It thus gives you backwards compatibility for older versions of the support library.

Backwards-compatibility for older versions of android is now built into the artifacts - `androidx.viewpager` will Just Work on Android SDK 14 and up. For what it's worth, the v4, v7, and v13 artifacts haven't meant "support for Android SDK 4+/7+/13+" [since the 26.0.0 release](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library#api-versions).

Answer (score 0):

If you have any Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace, the Android Studio build system also migrates those dependencies for you when you set the following two flags to true in your gradle.properties file:

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

To migrate an existing project that does not use any third-party libraries with dependencies that need converting, you can set the android.useAndroidX flag to true and the android.enableJetifier flag to false.

more info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate